# Rotate an image in python and fill the cropped area with image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

Have a look at the image and it will give you the better idea what I want to achieve. I want to rotate the image and fill the black part of image just like in required image.  [image]

```
# Read the image
img = cv2.imread("input.png")

# Get the image size
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# Define the rotation matrix
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w/2, h/2), 30, 1)

# Rotate the image
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h))

mask = np.zeros(rotated.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
mask[np.where((rotated == [0, 0, 0]).all(axis=2))] = 255
img_show(mask)
```

From the code I am able to get the mask of black regions. Now I want to replace these black regions with the image portion as shown in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ymji.png). Any better solution how can I achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the `borderMode` parameter of `warpAffine`.

You want to pass the [`BORDER_WRAP`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5aed2e4346047e265c8c5a6d0276dcd838) value.

Here's the result. This does exactly what you described with your first picture.

[image]

Comment: I don't want the black region at the side of images. does this maintain this decorum.

Comment: did you try it? I wrote this answer specifically because it exactly does what you want.

Comment: Let me check the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach. You can first create a larger image consisting of 3 * 3 times your original image. When you rotate this image and only cut out the center of this large image, you have your desired result.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the image
img = cv2.imread("input.png")

# Get the image size of the origial image
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# make a large image containing 3 copies of the original image in each direction
large_img = np.tile(img, [3,3,1])

cv2.imshow("large_img", large_img)

# Define the rotation matrix. Rotate around the center of the large image
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w*3/2, h*3/2), 30, 1)

# Rotate the image
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(large_img, M, (w*3, h*3))

# crop only the center of the image
cropped_image = rotated[w:w*2,h:h*2,:]

cv2.imshow("cropped_image", cropped_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I think this is *unnecessary* complication. `warpAffine()` has a `borderMode` parameter for this specific purpose.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about the border mode, I did not know about the existence of the border mode. I upvoted your answer.